# Empty json array in fromJson

Tags: android, json, gson

In my Get method, I am deserializing an array response like this -

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
if (httpEntity != null) {
    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    Header contentEncoding = httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
        inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
    }

String resultString = convertStreamToString(inputStream); // final json string response object

if(resultString == "{}")
{
     resultString = "[]";
     Log.d("result", "in the condition");
}

inputStream.close();
return new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);
}
```

The `objectClass` is being sent as `Product[].class`

All this works fine, unless resultString is empty (no data is returned by api). When that is the case, deserialization fails. I tried to change `resultString` to an empty array json but the condition itself is not satisfied.

Please tell how to deserialize an empty json to return empty object (and not null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I printed `resultString.length()` and it came out to be `3`. Not sure why this is the case when the string itself is `{}`. May be there is a newline char, but I am not sure. So, I changed the condition to checking length instead and things work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code this:

```
if(resultString == "{}")
{
     resultString = "[]";
     Log.d("result", "in the condition");
}
```

to:

```
if(resultString.equals("{}"))
{
     Log.d("result", "in the condition");
     inputStream.close();
     return objectClass();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't think that is the issue here. It is most likely to recognize what is the empty json here.

Comment: What do you mean by empty is it null, or just "" ?

Comment: just check if the resultString.equals("{}") if it is then return a new Object of type of your Class

Comment: The control is not going into the condition itself.

Comment: write this before the condition just to check what the string looks like when it is empty Log.d("result", resultString );

Comment: It shows {} but still not satisfying the condition.